# Listview cuts complete sentence - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically loading some text in the jquery mobile listview to show as a list. Now if a big text came listview cuts it to adjust in a single line. List is simple

```
<ol data-role="listview">
    <li>Acura hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh jjjjjjjjjjjjj kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk hhhhhh aaaaaaa sssssss</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ol>
```

first on the list gets cut off. see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cg9g4p2/)

What's the way to adjust height width according to text size for listview? Is there any simple trick or do I need to write dirty css. I was thinking of some native trick.

Comment: see this : http://jsfiddle.net/0cg9g4p2/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS to make the text wrap to the next line is:

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-static {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

To make the text continue off the screen, allowing the user to scroll horizontally to see the remaining text:

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-static {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0cg9g4p2/3/)